# Does universe calculate?

Tags: universe

This is probably totally naive (philosophical?) question. I am not mathematician nor physicist so maybe it is quite dumb question too.

1. IF universe does calculate, how does it cope with numbers like 1/3, PI, etc. ?
2. IF universe does not calculate, does this **theoretically** mean there could be (opposed to mathematics/physics) some other (non-invented yet) tool/mechanism for describing the universe, where there would be **no need** for approximations of numbers like 1/3, PI, etc?

If one would try to model **a whole star** (containing enormous number of different particles, external gravitational  influences, etc.) as detailed as possible with nowadays knowledge of mathematics/physics, what would be the outcome of such a calculation if one would have to make numerous approximations (mentioned above) all the time?

Comment: What does it even *mean* to say "The universe does calculate" vs. "The universe does not calculate"? The universe is not (as far as we know) conscious.

Comment: Also, what does `1/3` have to do with approximations? It's exact, and it can be used in an exact way. One third of 71 exactly 23 2/3.

Comment: The OP seems to think "1/3's decimal expansion has an infinite number of digits, so nothing with a finite memory capacity can truly represent it exactly". But of course this isn't true - the repeating representation is only a consequence of the base you're using. Switch to base 9, and 1/3 can be represented in two digits: 0.3.

Comment: How much wood would the universe chuck if a universe could chuck wood?

Comment: In a sense, yes. I am a part of the universe, and I calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universe does not "calculate". The universe just exists as it is and evolves. We calculate things like how far a particle with a given speed goes in a given time because we don't actually have the particle or the time. The universe just has everything in a state, has the laws of nature in place, and everything works itself out.

In the universe an actual particle starts at some speed and time takes it however far it can go. No calculation required. The universe has all the resources necessary. With these, all it has to have is have initial conditions, have laws that guide the actions of things in it, and have time for the actions of those laws to run. This isn't a mechanism we can always use. There will always come a point where we don't actually have the thing/process we want to analyze, so we will have to use calculations and numbers to represent that thing/process.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Pray tell; what confusion might it cause?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I don't, presently, have enough time to go through the articles. But even if there is a legitimate concern of added confusion, I'd be willing to bet that any confusion caused by my answer is less than the initial confusion the OP had before reading my answer. I call that a net gain

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick It's not that I find it unhelpful, I just don't quite know what changes you are trying to suggest. As hinted at before, I'm heading out right now, but if you can think of suggestions and want to leave them with me, I'll take a look when I get back

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yeah, that's good. It's essentially exactly the same thing as what I said, but in more abstract words. If you want to edit it to say that, be my guest